# email templates loop

Tags: email, loop, template

I have some strings variables:

test1
test2
test3
...

Each of them with some text inside

I have in my html email template :

test1
test2
test3
..

I would like to know how to iterate with :

```
body = body.replace('test1',test1);
```

Not manually like that but directly in a loop.

I was thinking about something like

```
 for (Integer i =0; i<10; ++i) {  


               body = body.replace(test[i],test[i]); 
           }
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the variables in the list:

```
List<String> test = new List<String>{test1, test2, test3, ...};
```

Then, when you are replacing variables in body, you need to replace String, not a variable, as in the question:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    body = body.replace('test' + String.valueOf(i+1), test[i]);
}
```

For example:

```
String test1 = '1';
String test2 = '22';
String test3 = '333';
List<String> test = new List<String>{test1, test2, test3};

String body = 'test1 got to the test2 and then test3 happen';

for (Integer i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    body = body.replace('test' + String.valueOf(i+1), test[i]);
}

system.debug(body); //1 got to the 22 and then 333 happen
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have still a small problem on my list of string (see edited version)

Comment: Regarding your update: try to mix the variables. For example, bound inputs and set them as string separated by ',' then split the String by comma and pass it into list.